# How to write a JASMINE test case for my method. Have been trying to mock the event listener. Please point to link or provide me with the mocks

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Trying to write a jasmine test for the below code...

refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable();

```
//Check if a new cache is available on page load and reload the page to refresh app cache to the newer version of files
function refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable() {
    $window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        $window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e) {
            if ($window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
                // Manifest changed. Now Browser downloadeds a new app cache.
                alert(textService.versioning.newVersionMessage);
                $window.location.reload(true);
            } else {
                // Manifest didn't change. Nothing new to server.
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you mainly just need to spy on a couple of `$window` methods. What **exactly** are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to write a SPY for the method.

spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').and.callFake(function () {
                return;
            });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your challenge**

I assume the challenge you are facing is that you are unable to see how to test the code in the callback functions. You just have to realize that you have access to the callback function when you spy on addEventListener, after the spy is executed in your service under test (`refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable`). Since you can get a reference to it, you can execute it, just as if it was the function you were testing.

**Sample solution**

The following is untested, written off the top of my head, but something along the lines of what I would expect to write if I had to test that code.

```
describe('refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable()', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn($window, 'addEventListener');
  });

  it('should register a load event handler on the window', function() {    
    refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable();

    expect($window.addEventListener.calls.count()).toBe(1);

    var args = $window.addEventListener.calls.argsFor(0);
    expect(args.length).toBe(3);
    expect(args[0]).toBe('load');
    expect(typeof args[1]).toBe('function');
    expect(args[2]).toBe(false);
  });

  describe('load event', function() {
    var loadFunction;

    beforeEach(function() {
      refreshCacheIfNewVersionIsAvailable();
      var args = $window.addEventListener.calls.argsFor(0);
      loadFunction = args[1];

      spyOn($window.applicationCache, 'addEventListener');
    });

    it('should register an updateready event handler in the window application cache', function() {
      loadFunction();

      expect($window.applicationCache.addEventListener.calls.count()).toBe(1);

      var args = $window.applicationCache.addEventListener.calls.argsFor(0);
      expect(args.length).toBe(3);
      expect(args[0]).toBe('updateReady');
      expect(typeof args[1]).toBe('function');
      expect(args[2]).toBe(false);
    });

    describe('updateready event', function() {
      var updateReadyFunction;

      beforeEach(function() {
        loadFunction();
        var args = $window.applicationCache.addEventListener.calls.argsFor(0);
        updateReadyFunction = args[1];
      });

      it('should reload the window if the status is UPDATEREADY', function() {
        // You get the point
      });
    });
  });
});
```